# Pass Object From One View to Other on Screen

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I want to create two `UIViews`. One has (lets say v1) list of `UIViews` instances inside while second one (v2) will empty initially. I want to pass object of v1 to v2 with animation. It should be like drag and drop from v1 to v2 with animation. Can anyone tell me how to do that? I just want to know the logic. Please help me.

Comment: you have to add your object to your main view and apply pan gesture to the object which has to be moved from one view to another. Now in your pan gesture handler you have to check that the object views center lies within the v1 or v2 if yes you have to move that object view to corresponding view by setting the frame of object view.

Comment: refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581378/ios-5-1-drag-and-drop

Comment: yes i need to use pan gesture...I think you have given right way to start that task...thanks @MayurShrivas ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just refer this project. Make necessary changes in your project.

https://github.com/Hegaka/HGKDragAndDropRecycleBin